# Pederson's Analysis now Proposition 4.5.10, Why is this operator equal to $0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

Here is an image of the proposition:

[image]

An highlighted below is the part of the proof I'm having trouble with.

[image]

Why is the equation true for every n?  $f_n(T) = \int_{\sigma(T)} f_n \: dE$, but I don't see how if you take some $x \in \ker(\lambda I-f(T))$ that then $f_n(T)x=0$.  I tried using the fact that: $$\lVert f_n(T)x \rVert^2 = \int_{\sigma(T)} f^2_n \: d\mu_{x,x}$$ but I'm failing to see how this integral is $0$, given that all I know about it is that $\mu_{x,x}(Y) = \langle E(Y)x,x \rangle$ on measurable subsets of the spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f_n = g_n(\lambda - f)$ where $g_n(t) = (|t| \wedge 1)^{1/n}$. $g_n$ is a continuous function with $g_n(0) = 0$, so it can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of polynomials $(g_{nm})_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ with zero constant term. Clearly, when $x \in \mathrm{ker}(\lambda I - f(T))$, $[g_{nm}(\lambda I - f(T))](x) = 0$, since $g_{nm}$ is a polynomial with no constant term and you can directly evaluate $g_{nm}(\lambda I - f(T))$ to see that this is the case. As $g_{nm} \to g_n$ uniformly, we see that $g_{nm}(\lambda I - f(T)) \to g_n(\lambda I - f(T)) = f_n(T)$, so $[f_n(T)](x) = 0$.

Comment: I see, this seems to work, but I don't see how $f_n=g_n$.  First, $g_n(\lambda - f)$ could be complex valued since $f$, $\lambda$ could be complex valued.  Secondly, if $f_n(\mu) = |\lambda - f(\mu)|^{1/n}$, but $|\mu| < 1$, then $g_n(\mu) = |\mu|^{1/n}(\lambda-f(\mu))$.  How are these both equal?

Comment: @Isochron I don’t understand what you meant? $g_n(\lambda - f)$ is just applying $g_n$ to $\lambda - f$, so you literally just plug in $\lambda - f$ for $t$ in the formula of $g_n(t)$ and you get the formula for $f_n$.

Comment: @Isochron I guess complex valued is a problem. I should have said $g_{nm}$ are polynomials in $t$ and $\bar{t}$ with no constant term, rather than just polynomials in $t$. But the proof goes through regardless.